# Part-time AL calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know this isn't necessarily programming but I have used this community many a time and you have always been able to provide guidance or an answer.

My business have asked me to calculate the Annual Leave for all of our staff for 2019 and update this. They have altered the way they want the AL to be calculated and so the previous calculator I built is now obsolete.

I have managed to make the calculation work for my full time staff as I am not having to take their FTE into consideration, even when they move up to a higher allocation of AL, based on their service with the company.

When it comes to part time staff, we have to also add in the bank holidays as they are entitled to them, and then take out the hours that they would be working on those bank holidays.

My issue is when the agent changes allocation half way through the year.

This is the calculation for an agent that stays within their allocation for the whole year.

(Allocation+BankHolidays)x(FTE)x(TimeWithinYearSpentInAllocation)

So as an example the calculation would be:

(172.5+(8x7.5))x(15/37.5)x(365/365)=93

From that number we would then subtract however many hours they would be "working" on bank holidays.

My issue is when they change allocation the below calculation doesn't work.

(172.5+(3x7.5))x(15/37.5)x(120/365)+(187.5+(5x7.5))x(15/37.5)x(245/365)= 88 (rounded)

Can anyone help me on a calculation that will help me get there?

Regards,

Jordan.

Comment: Well, first why don't you split the calculation down into separate bits to find out which bit is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi Mike, the issue currently is that breaking up the bank holidays over the two allocations is producing lower numbers.

Comment: In the "Formulas" tab, there is a button "Evaluate Formula", where formulas get evaluated step by step, which allows you to see at which step the calculation does not correspond to your wishes. Did you already try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the bank holidays. Just remove the allocation part and comapre the results:

```
 ((8*7,5))*(15/37,5)*(365/365)=24
 ((3*7,5))*(15/37,5)*(120/365)=3
 ((5*7,5))*(15/37,5)*(245/365)=10
```

this doesnt make sense. I dont know laws in your country, but for me if I work over public holidays I am entiteled to the same number of hours leave but here you calculate that if you work for 3 days of public holidays you are entiteled for 3 hours of leave. Shouldnt the days*hours be added after the multiplication of the allocation?

Comment: Hi Pavel,That is generally how it would work but with this company they are saying all employees are entitled to 7.5 hours per public holiday.

Comment: yes, but if you include part time employees in your "all employees" than your calculation is not adding them 7,5 hours per day of public holidays. If the calculation was like this (172.5)x(15/37.5)x(365/365)+(8x7.5) then it would mean adding 7,5 hours per day of public holiday.

Comment: Hi Pavel,

The won't be working, but the calculation asks you to calculate as if they didn't work any days and so they would get the full allocation of 60 multiplied by their FTE. Then we remove the amount of hours that they take off instead of working, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think I might have figured it out

Comment: what about the multiplication by the TimeWithinYearSpentInAllocation? Couldnt it be this way? =(172,5*(365/365)+(8*7,5))*(15/37,5)
Because then the parts would give me the same number in total
=(172,5*(120/365)+(3*7,5))*(15/37,5)+(172,5*(245/365)+(5*7,5))*(15/37,5)

Comment: PAVEL YOU ARE A GENUIS. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help